# Python 3.11 SQLAlchemy insert 1 row

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Was working in Python 3.6 and my code was working properly but I recently switched to 3.11 and it's no longer running my code properly. Here are the details of the code that pertain to this specific instance.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import numpy as np
import pyodbc as db
import math
import os
import sys
import win32com.client as win32
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import io

start_time = datetime.now()
log_name = 'bds_strategic_firm_download'
log_status = 'N'
log_user = "US\\" + str(os.environ.get("USERNAME"))

connection_string = (
           r"Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
           r"Server=SERVERVALUES;"
           r"Database=DATABASEVALUES;"
           r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
           )
connection_url = URL.create(
           "mssql+pyodbc", 
           query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
           )
engine = create_engine(connection_url, fast_executemany=True)
autocommit_engine = engine.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
connection1 = autocommit_engine.connect()
connection = engine.connect()

connection.execute("insert into [GrpReposUserDev1_dv].[dbo].[mvp_python_logs] (log_name, start_time, log_status, log_user) values(?, ?, ?, ?)", (log_name, start_time, log_status, log_user))
```

I am expecting 1 row of values to be inserted in to my MSSQL table as they were previously. The values are data types of - str, datetime.datetime, str, str

I tried to the above code and am receiving the below error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Code\Python\strategicfirmhierarchy.py", line 112, in <module>
    connection.execute("insert into [GrpReposUserDev1_dv].[dbo].[mvp_python_logs] (log_name, start_time, log_status, log_user) \
  File "C:\Users\KW69\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1410, in execute
    distilled_parameters = _distill_params_20(parameters)
  File "lib\\sqlalchemy\\cyextension\\util.pyx", line 26, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.util._distill_params_20
  File "lib\\sqlalchemy\\cyextension\\util.pyx", line 17, in sqlalchemy.cyextension.util._check_item
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries
```

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson SQLAlchemy 2.0.23

Comment: Then you'll need to use `connection.exec_driver_sql()` instead of `connection.execute()` for a DBAPI-specific insert.

Comment: @GordThompson - wonderful, I appreciate your help!